# How to use an AndroidAnnotations SharedPref with a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I have a PreferenceActivity that I'd like to use with AndroidAnnotations @SharedPref, so the PreferenceActivity would use the data in the @SharedPref.

Is there a good way to do this?  How do I tell the activity to to use @SharedPref I created elsewhere?  Is there a good way to do this without setting the value of each preference?

Here is the activity code I'm currently using:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **PreferenceActivity** is an **Activity**, so you just need to annotate it with **@EActivity** to start using the annotations, such as **@SharedPref**.

If you want to share preferences between activities, AndroidAnnotations has the notion of scope, as defined [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/SharedPreferencesHelpers).

You should use the **Scope.UNIQUE** scope to share it between all activities.

SharedPref were thought as a way to easily store data into SharedPreferences. Not necessarily to be used with **PreferenceActivity**.

You can use **getSharedPreferences()** to access the shared preferences instance, you can't use that to define the preference to use in the activity. So it's mainly a matter of using the right Android APIs.

```
@EActivity
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Pref
    MyPrefs_ myPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("MyPrefs");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```